# Set max-height to position: sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div's. The upper div uses `position: sticky`, the bottom div should be placed after the first div.

However, when there is many rows in the first div, it takes all screen and the second div cannot be seen.

I've tried to use, but sticky div did not change its height:

```css
max-height: 60%;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Does anybody know how it is possible to set `max-height` to sticky position and create scroll in the first div?

My code looks like this:

```css
.mainContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}

.stickyContainer {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: lightgreen;
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.scrollable {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
      <div class="stickyContainer">
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
        <p>sticky container</p>
      </div>

      <div class="scrollable">
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
        <p>scrollable content</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: The max-height wont apply because you try to apply a percentage height with a container that does not have a defined height. Replace it by `max-height: 60vh` and it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **vh**?

```
.stickyContainer {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: lightgreen;
    max-height:60vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I've used percentage, but it works with `vh`! Have a good day:)